# Wait for redux action to finish dispatching when using redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a redux saga setup which works fine. One of my dispatches is to create a new order, then once that has been created I want to do things with the updated state.

```
// this.props.userOrders = []

dispatch(actions.createOrder(object))

doSomethingWith(this.props.userOrders)
```

Since the createOrder action triggers a redux saga which calls an API, there is a delay, so this.props.userOrders is not updated before my function doSomethingWith is called. I could set a timeout, but that doesn't seem like a sustainable idea.

I have read the similar questions on Stack Overflow, and have tried implementing the methods where relevant, but I can't seem to get it working. I'm hoping with my code below that someone can just add a couple of lines which will do it.

Here are the relevant other files:

**actions.js**

export const createUserOrder = (data) => ({
  type: 'CREATE_USER_ORDER',
  data
})

**Sagas.js**

```
function * createUserOrder () {
  yield takeEvery('CREATE_USER_ORDER', callCreateUserOrder)
}

export function * callCreateUserOrder (newUserOrderAction) {
  try {
    const data = newUserOrderAction.data
    const newUserOrder = yield call(api.createUserOrder, data)
    yield put({type: 'CREATE_USER_ORDER_SUCCEEDED', newUserOrder: newUserOrder})
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({type: 'CREATE_USER_ORDER_FAILED', error})
  }
}
```

**Api.js**

```
export const createUserOrder = (data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  api.post('/userOrders/', data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        reject(response)
      } else {
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
})
```

**orders reducer:**

```
case 'CREATE_USER_ORDER_SUCCEEDED':
   if (action.newUserOrder) {
      let newArray = state.slice()
      newArray.push(action.newUserOrder)
          return newArray
       } else {
       return state
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't be "waiting" inside a component's lifecycle function / event handler at any point, but rather make use of the current state of the store.

If I understand correctly, this is your current flow:

> You dispatch an action `CREATE_USER_ORDER` in your React component. This action is consumed by your `callCreateUserOrder` saga. When your create order saga is complete, it dispatches another "completed" action, which you already have as `CREATE_USER_ORDER_SUCCEEDED`.

What you should now add is the proper reducer/selector to handle your `CREATE_USER_ORDER_SUCCEEDED`:

This `CREATE_USER_ORDER_SUCCEEDED` action should be handled by your reducer to create a new state where some "orders" property in your state is populated. This can be connected directly to your component via a selector, at which point your component will be re-rendered and `this.props.userOrders` is populated.

---

Example:

*component*

```
class OrderList extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    userOrders: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    createOrder: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  addOrder() {
    this.props.createOrder({...})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Button onClick={this.addOrder}>Add Order</Button>
        <List>{this.props.userOrders.map(order => <Item>{order.name}</Item>)}</List>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userOrders: state.get('userOrders'),
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  createOrder: () => ({ type: 'CREATE_ORDER', payload: {} }),
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrderList)
```

---

*reducer*

```
case 'CREATE_USER_ORDER_SUCCEEDED':
  return state.update('userOrders',
    orders => orders.concat([payload.newUserOrder])
  )
```

---

If you really do need side-effects, then add those side-effects to your saga, or create a new saga that takes the SUCCESS action.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Apologies, I forgot to add my reducer to my question, I've done that now at the bottom of it. Everything you've said I agree with, and I'm actually doing. The problem is that this.props.userOrders doesn't get updated quickly enough, I am using it on the next line of my code, so I need to 'wait' to know when to use it. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just to clarify, rendering the updated orders isn't the problem, it's doing something with this.props.userOrders straight after it which is the problem. Thanks

Comment: @moinhaque can you provide an example of why you want to "wait"? What I'm saying is that you should redesign your approach so that you don't "wait". Use another saga that takes the success action if you need to. Don't dispatch an action and immediately wait for it in the same function within the component.

Comment: I'm using that dispatch to make a new order, then my next step is to create a payment for that order which the user then pays within the app (hence why I'm doing it in the component). Not sure if adding another Saga will solve it, but I'll look into it.

Comment: All good and well, but imagine that you have for example a POST which should display either validation errors or navigate to another page... Not every result should be something that will trigger a `render()`... So how to handle this with dispatch/selectors: `this.api.editObject.then(navigate...).catch(...validationErrors)`

Comment: With Redux saga you would have the API call and handler in a saga. Validation errors are dispatched from the saga and reduce the state so the store contains error messages. With the new React hooks (or even where you choose not to use sagas, after all it's a specific design pattern), you would handle the API from within the component.